# How to use certificate stored in windows certificates manager using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ssl

1. My python application is running locally on `http://0.0.0.0:80/`
2. Later, to make SSL connection I generated MyCert.crt and Mycert.key files.
3. Later, after providing the location of certificate and key files. My application works perfect and starts running over https connection as per expectation.

   code snippet: 
   from OpenSSL import SSL

   context = ("C:/myCert.crt", "C:/Mycert.key")
   app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port='80',ssl_context = context)
4. Now, I import the same certificate to: windows certificates manager -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities. It shows certificate name as **localhost**
5. Now, my goal is to access the certificate for same python application and start using it from windows certificate manager. 
   I referred couple of libraries(requests, wincertstore) but I am unable to understand them as I am new in this domain.

How Do I modify my python code to access this certificate.

Answer (score -1):

you need to change your port firstly, 443 will be great (as far as we know, https go over 443)
and replace your line with this one:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=443, debug=True, ssl_context=('/home/ubuntu/cert/myCert.pem', '/home/ubuntu/cert/myCert2.pem'))
```

read this article, it will help you:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

Comment: I have similar implementation of accessing the files which are stored locally. But, since my certificate is stored in windows certificate manager. How do I provide the path for it?